# Using React modal component

Tags: reactjs

I have a component 'Building' which contains a Modal that contains data from the 'building' object, see code:

```
  <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
      <Modal.Title>{building.name}</Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body><p>Purchase Price : {purchase_price}</p></Modal.Body>
    <Modal.Footer>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
        Save Changes
      </Button>
    </Modal.Footer>
  </Modal>
```

This works exactly as expected, I click a button on the screen and the modal pops up with details from the object, 'building'.

What I'd like to do is separate the Modal from the Building component so I can add more fields, and possibly reference it in other locations, but I'm unclear how I should incorporate that.

I want the modal to work something like this :

```
import '../css/modal.css';
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { Modal, Button}  from 'react-bootstrap'

  return (
    <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>{building.name}</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
        <p>Purchase Price : {purchase_price}</p>
        <p>something : {something}</p>
        <p>something : {something}</p>
        <p>something : {something}</p>
        <p>something : {something}</p>
        <p>something : {something}</p>
        <p>something : {something}</p>
        <p>something : {something}</p>
        <p>something : {something}</p>
        <p>something : {something}</p>
        <p>something : {something}</p>
        <p>something : {something}</p>
        <p>something : {something}</p>

      </Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
          Save Changes
        </Button>
    </Modal.Footer>
  </Modal>
  );
};

export default Modal
```

I don't know how to include the reference to this modal, and pass the Building object.

Any suggestions?

Update:
I tried the suggestion below by creating a functional component, copying the example provided by @jade.

```
import React from 'react';


const buildingModal = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Purchase Price: {props.purchase_price}</p>
      <p>Purchase Date: {props.purchase_date}</p>
      <p>ZPID: {props.zpid}</p>
    </div>
);
}

export default buildingModal;
```

I don't think I'm importing or consuming the values correctly because while I get no error from the below block, I also get nothing returned.

```
import buildingModal from './buildingModal';
...
<Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
      <Modal.Title>{building.name}</Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>
    <div></div>
    <Modal.Body><buildingModal building={building}</Modal.Body>
    <Modal.Footer>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
        Save Changes
      </Button>
    </Modal.Footer>
  </Modal>
```

Am I mistaken in thinking that the entire object would be displayed in the <Modal.Body> segment? I don't want to have to reference each element individually.

Update 2:
Here is the building component. The setup is the home screen calls the building component and that then opens the modal with details. I'm looking to separate the details into a separate component and insert it back into the modal window that building opens. No matter how I try this, I can't get anything passed into the separate modal component, or at least nothing shows up on the screen.

```
//building.js    
    import React, {useState} from 'react';
    import {Modal, Button}  from 'react-bootstrap';
    import logoImg from '../img/logo3.svg';
    import CurrencyFormat from 'react-currency-format';
    
    function Building({building}) {
      const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
      const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
      const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
      const iURL = building.imageURL
      const purchase_price = <CurrencyFormat value={building.purchase_price} displayType={'text'} thousandSeparator={true} prefix={'$'} />
    
      return (
        <div className="row bs">
          <div className="col-md-4 left">
            <div>
            {iURL ? (
              <img src ={building.imageURL} className="smallimg"/>
            ) : (
              <img src ={logoImg} className="smallimg" />
            )}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-7 mt-0">
            <h2>{building.name}</h2>
              <p>{building.city}, {building.state} {building.zip}</p>
            <div style={{ float: "center" }} onClick={handleShow}>
              <button className="btn btn-primary">View Details</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <>
          <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
            <Modal.Header>
              <Modal.Title>{building.name}</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <div></div>
            <Modal.Body><p>Purchase Price : {purchase_price}</p></Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
              <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
                Close
              </Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
          </Modal>
        </>
    
        <h1></h1>
        </div>
    
      )
    }
    
    export default Building
```

The home screen looks like this:
[image]

and the modal currently looks like this:
[image]

I want to add a lot more datapoints to the details modal and that's why I'm looking to separate it.

Answer (score 0):

Kool, you want to design a component, say ModalOk.

```
  // figure out the interface
  const ModalOk({ show, handleClose }) => {
    return (
      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        ...
      </Modal>
    )
  }
```

So this component is expecting `show` and `handleClose` to be provided via props.

```
  <ModalOk show={on} handleClose={onClose} />
```

Search internet on topics like React function component etc. Or most of the tutorial should cover how to design a component. Of course you are doing some more advanced stuff, ex. consuming something that is not designed by you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply build a function component for the modal you'd like to build.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

const CustomModalBody = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{props.price}</p>
      <p>{props.something1}</p>
      <p>{props.something2}</p>
    </div>
)
}

export default CustomModalBody;
```

Then you can simply import the component to your main modal component and pass whatever values you'd like to display.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, still dealing with some issues. See my update in the main post. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Where are you getting {building} from? Can you add the building object to your question as well?

Comment: Added the building component.